# Let B be a set of sets. Suppose that (UB) ⊆ U{(X):X∈B}. Prove that for every A ∈ B there is an X ∈ B such that A ⊆ X.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is a lot of information given here and I'm not sure what to do with it all. I'm not sure what approach to take to prove this statement.

Comment: There is a typo in the title, $S$ is appearing from nowhere

Comment: Sorry! That S should be an X

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to the defining property of powerset and union :

$$Y \in \mathcal{P}(B) \Longleftrightarrow Y \subseteq B $$
$$Y \in \bigcup B \Longleftrightarrow \exists b \in B, Y \in b$$
Assume $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup B) = \bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(X) \ \big| \ X \in B\}$.

Let $A \in B$. We first show that $A \subseteq \bigcup B$ :
Let $a \in A$, then $a \in \bigcup B$ by the defining property above, qed.

Since $A \subseteq \bigcup B$, $A \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcup B)$. Hence, 
$A \in \bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(X) \ \big| \ X \in B\}$ by assumption.

Hence, there is $X \in B$ such that $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, ie $A \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you may have mis-copied the problem. The statement in your title is trivial. For every $A\in B$, there is an $X\in B$, namely $X=A$, such that $A\subseteq X$. (Notice that the assumption about power sets and unions isn't needed for this.)

Very probably the problem should have said "Prove that there is an $X\in B$ such that, for every $A\in B$, we have $A\subseteq X$."  To prove this, we use the assumption about power sets and unions along with the fact that $\bigcup B\in\mathcal P(\bigcup B)$ to infer that $\bigcup B\in\bigcup\{\mathcal P(X):X\in B\}$.  So there is an $X\in B$ such that $\bigcup B\in\mathcal P(X)$.  For this $X$, we have $\bigcup B\subseteq X$. For any $A\in B$, we also have $A\subseteq\bigcup B$, and so $A\subseteq X$, as required.